# How to format the Ubuntu partitions from Windows XP?

Tags: partitioning, dual-boot, windows-xp

How to format the Ubuntu partitions from Windows XP?

My Ubuntu is broken and can't log in.  My dual booting Windows XP is working fine.  I want to delete Ubuntu partitions from Windows XP and reinstall.  How to delete the partitions?

Comment: No need to delete - you can just re-install and format the existing ubuntu partition.

Comment: simply select replace ubuntu with ubuntu

or select something else from the setup and do it as if u are doing a fresh install

Answer (score 3):

No need to delete. It will cause break in grub. Xp won't be bootable.

- Just put the live cd/usb and reinstall ubuntu.That will solve the problem.

If you really want to delete partition, open disk management in XP (`diskmgmt.msc`) and right click on ubuntu drives and click delete.

- Now to fix the boot, boot using windows xp disk. Open recovery console and type fixboot and fixmbr commands. A description is [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/termsf/p/fixboot.htm)

---

Update:

Since you have deleted the partition and want to re install ubuntu as duel boot. Do the followings,

- Boot using ubuntu live usb/cd.
- Choose "Do something else" in ubuntu installer.
- Select the free space created by deleting ubuntu previously. (If there is no free space, probably you have formatted the drrive with ntfs. Locate the drive and click on delete.). Now click on **`ADD`**. Enter a small amount of space Like 1024MB, and choose `SWAP` from the filesystem dropdown.
- Again click on the remaining free space. This time choose File system as `ext4` and mount point as `/`. Now you are good to go for installation.After installation all OS will be accessible.

If you want to boot only XP. Follow instruction [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/termsf/p/fixboot.htm). Need to have XP disk.

Comment: Thanks for answer.  But now it's already too late.  I have deleted the partition using a bootable USB with Ubuntu installer. And as you expected, I have a broken bootloader and can't start any OS on this machine now.  What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to install Ubuntu again? if yes, follow Web-E's answer. If you only want to use XP, and you have a `grub-rescue >` prompt at boot screen,

- try entering these command:

  - `ls` to see all the partion.
  - detect your XP partition.
  - Set the root device by entering `set root=(hd0,msdosX)`, where `X` refers to the partition where XP resides.*(assuming you have only one disk)*
  - Then enter `chainloader +1` command
  - then type `boot` and press enter

It will boot the computer to XP. After booting to the Xp, you should reenable the Xp's bootloader. download the bootsect.exe file from here [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3dzjkzchulm5q7i/NEGtnZ3_wX/Bootsect.exe). Open cmd.exe with Administrative power, and `cd` to the directory where you downloaded the file and enter this command `bootsect.exe /nt52 ALL /force /mbr`. Now restart to see whether this works. (XP will by default open the `cmd.exe` as administrator).

Answer (score -2):

You can delete the partition from the Ubuntu Installer, If you *really* want it from XP then http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/dm_delete_partition.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: This will cause a non bootable system as GRUB will fail.

Comment: Exactly what I experienced.